# how to check if a special case character is in a google sheet cell?

Tags: google-sheets, special-characters

I working on google sheets files where any special case character (any character other than [a-z,A-Z,0-9] ) is forbidden so to confirm this condition is true I need to check that every character in the cell isn't equal to any special case character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!
One of the many possible ways (not the most correct, but visual) - replace all the correct, valid characters with an empty string, just remove them from the cell text, and compare the result with an empty string: the result of the comparison will return TRUE if as a result of such a replacement there are no left in the text no character and FALSE otherwise.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[0-9,a-z,A-Z]","")=""
```

Or try to extract all characters from the cell text that are not valid. If there are no such characters, then the REGEXEXTRACT() function will return an error and this will be a signal that the cell is "correct":

```
=ISERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[^0-9,a-z,A-Z]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional formatting to get a visual representation of cells with special case characters.
All you need to do is apply this formula on the whole sheet or on the range of cells you prefer:

```
=len(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[^0-9a-zA-Z]"))
```

[image: regex]